# Pass object with methods between languages

Tags: java, c#, android, serialization

The following C# code enables creating an object in one program, serialize it and send it to an endpoint. The reciever can deserialize the data and invoke one of the object methods.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    private int myInt;
    private string myString;

    public MyClass(int i, string s) ...
    public virtual void SayHello()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Sender:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(1, "a");
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(someOutputStream, myClass);
```

Receiver:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MyClass myClass = formatter.Deserialize(someInputStream) as MyClass;
myClass?.SayHello();
```

This functionallity is made possible if both sides have the same dll with MyClass decleration.

My question is: Is this functionallity possible when it comes to communication between C# server and Java client(android)?

I have read about Google ProtoBuf functionality, which allowes only data serialization but does not support methods declaration.

The final purpose is to create an object on the server side and run it's method
on the client side.

Comment: Being able to pass arbitrary code to another computer sounds like an unnecessary security risk.

Comment: No. Java and C# produce incompatible byte code which cannot be interpreted by the other languages runtime.

Comment: no, it's impossible.

Comment: with a `web service` you can

Comment: To pass behavior you'd have to write same class in both languages. Then you can pass data between them using arbitrary well-known format (inlcuding ProtoBufs). This is the only way it can work.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer follows...

A large part of transferring data between heterogenous systems is ensuring that 1) the data meaning is intact, and 2) that the constraints on the data have been honoured. Whilst many serialisation technologies satisfy 1), not many satisfy 2). Examples are XSD/XML, and ASN.1. JSON schemas can also express constraints, I'm a little uncertain as to whether the tooling does a decent job of implementing them.

By "constraint" I mean a restriction on the value of a numerical or text quantity, the size of an array, and so forth. Imagine that if a field in a message was called 'bearing', it might make sense to constrain it to be 0->359. Thus if one program has sent 360, the recipient automatically rejects the message as being out of specification. A decent serialisation technology wouldn't let you send the 360 in the first place, raising an error during serialisation.

I mention this only because 1) it's attainable, and 2) it removes a large part of the drudgery in what you're trying to do. Yes, you will still have to reimplement the methods in Java on Android, but at least you won't have to check that what has been deserialised is valid. That will save you some time.

Another possibilty is code generation. Tools like Enterprise Architect (go with at least the Systems Engineering edition) allow you to define state machines in UML, and then generate functional code from them in a language of your choice. Thus an Enterprise Architect design model could be your "single point of truth", with C# and Java implementations generated from that. That's probably a lot of setting up, familiarisation, etc. but it could be made to work. More expensive versions of such tools (Artisan Designer?) do a more comprehensive job of this kind of thing, but that's very expensive... Enterprise Architect is pretty cheap, a couple of hundred dollars, ish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function written by another language, you can consider swig.

If you want to pass a custom function to another computer, another language, you perhaps shall writing a wrapper using the same language on both computers.